# Connection.State Issue

Tags: asp.net, connection

I've published my new website , In my computer it works fine and no problem , But in the Server I when some user connect at the same time it crash .
I found out There is a error at this Method :

```
public static DbDataReader ExecuteReader(DbCommand dbCommand, CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
{
    if (dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        dbConnection.Open();
    return dbCommand.ExecuteReader(commandBehavior);
}
```

When i trace it , It says ConnectionState is not open , and  it's doing opening . Here are my questions :
1- Is it a problem if while ConnectionState is doing opening , we Open the connection again ? 
2- What I've missed , that i receive this error ?

**Edit** 
For more information I past some part of my code here :

```
public class DbProviderHelper
    {
        private static DbProviderFactory dbProviderFactory;

        private static DbConnection dbConnection;

        #region dbConnexion

        public static DbConnection GetConnection()
        {
            if (dbConnection == null)
            {
                ConnectionStringsSection connectionStringsSection = GetConnectionStringsSection();
                dbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings[1].ProviderName);
                dbConnection = dbProviderFactory.CreateConnection();
                dbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString;
            }
            return dbConnection;
        }
        public static ConnectionStringsSection GetConnectionStringsSection()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;
        }

        #endregion dbConnexion

        #region  dbCommand

        public static DbCommand CreateCommand(String commandText, CommandType commandType)
        {
            DbCommand dbCommand = dbProviderFactory.CreateCommand();
            dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
            dbCommand.CommandType = commandType;
            dbCommand.CommandText = commandText;


            return dbCommand;
        }

        #endregion  dbCommand

        #region dbParameter

        public static DbParameter CreateParameter(string parameterName, DbType dbType, object value)
        {
            DbParameter oDbParameter = dbProviderFactory.CreateParameter();
            oDbParameter.ParameterName = parameterName;
            oDbParameter.DbType = dbType;
            oDbParameter.Value = value;

            return oDbParameter;
        }

        #endregion dbParameter

        #region Operations

        public static DbDataReader ExecuteReader(DbCommand dbCommand)
        {
            if (dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                dbConnection.Open();
            return dbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }
        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand dbCommand)
        {
            try
            {
                if (dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    dbConnection.Open();
                return dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        #endregion Operations

    }
```

And i invote that like :

```
public class Configuration
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        DbProviderHelper.GetConnection();
    }
    public DbDataReader GetTabsParent(int tabId)
    {
        DbCommand oDbCommand = DbProviderHelper.CreateCommand("Portal_TabsGetParent", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        oDbCommand.Parameters.Add(DbProviderHelper.CreateParameter("@TabID", DbType.Int32, tabId));
        DbDataReader oDbDataReader = DbProviderHelper.ExecuteReader(oDbCommand);
        return oDbDataReader;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think it is possible to determine the cause from the information you have provided...

Comment: Are you using the MS Data Application block? Can you tell us more about your connection string? Have you tried opening writing something from scratch to make sure the connection works as expected?

Comment: @Greg :No i don't , Instead i'm using DbProviderHelper of CS2Gen . I used that file in my project

Comment: @Mitch: I Edited my post and put some code sample , Hope this would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a problem if while ConnectionState is doing opening , we Open the connection again?

Yes, it can throw an exception.

Straight from [MSDN: SqlConnection.Open method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open.aspx)

> `InvalidOperationException`:
>   Cannot open a connection without specifying a data source or server.
>   or
>   The connection is already open

(are you executing the method on different threads with a single shared connection?)